# Force browser on top and work in other windows

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to force a browser window on top of all other windows and work in other windows at the same time?

I'm trying to make a webpage that gives the user extra information. This window needs to stay in front of Avaya interaction center. But ofcourse the user needs to be able to continue working in other browser windows/ apps.

I tried:

```
 `<body onBlur="window.focus()">`
```

But that prevents users from working in anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a webpage, no. You cannot interact with OS in that manner. If you have an option to deploy your webpage as an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app, then you could leverage something like [`win.setAlwaysOnTop`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel).

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with the browser for security reasons. Manipulate browser is impossible .
If in your case it's for noble reasons it can be use for bad reason and block users, imagine you put a website in fullscreen and force it in top you can block the computer for basic user. More dangerous actions are also possible if you allow this kind of action.